# Keep getting warning "Suggest parentheses around '&&' within '||' for C program

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, parentheses

```
 printf(" 1|        %d       |         %d         |       %d    |   %d  |     %d\n", 
    ((coffee_strength == 'm' || coffee_strength == 'M') && 
     (coffee1_type == 'l' || coffee1_type == 'L') || 
     (coffee_strength == 'r' || coffee_strength == 'R') && 
     (coffee1_type == 'b' || coffee1_type == 'B')), 
    ((coffee_maker == 'r' || coffee_maker == 'R') && 
     (coffee1_grindSize == 'c' || coffee1_grindSize == 'C') ||
     (coffee_maker == 'C' || coffee_maker == 'c') &&
     (coffee1_grindSize == 'f' || coffee1_grindSize == 'F')),
    ((coffee_servings >= 1) && (coffee_servings <= 4) &&
     (coffee1_weight >= 0) && (coffee1_weight <= 250) ||
     ((coffee_servings >= 1) && (coffee_servings <= 9) &&
      (coffee1_weight == 500)) || 
     ((coffee_servings >= 10) && (coffee1_weight == 1000))),
    (((coffee_cream == 'y' || coffee_cream == 'Y') &&
      (coffee1_cream == 'y' || coffee1_cream == 'Y') ||
      (coffee_cream == 'n' || coffee_cream == 'N') &&
      (coffee1_cream == 'n' || coffee1_cream == 'N'))),
    ((coffee1_temp >= 60.0) && (coffee1_temp <= 69.9) &&
     (coffee_maker == 'r' || coffee_maker == 'R') || 
     ((coffee1_temp >= 70.0) && (coffee_maker == 'c' ||  coffee_maker == 'C'))));
```

This is my code that I am trying to compile. Everytime I run it I still get the issue related to bracket placement. I have edited my code many times to try and solve this but the issue still persists. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I should do?

Comment: Please don't write overly long lines like that. Those are all but impossible to read and understand. Simplify your code to make it readable, understandable, and then also maintainable. Simpler code and simpler expressions should also help understanding issues like the one you ask about. For one way to make it simpler, read up on the [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) and [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) functions.

Comment: As for your problem, you basically have `a && b || c && d`, which is the problem the compiler is warning you about.

Comment: That's impressive. Completely unreadable though, and I'm not sure anyone knows what it really does, not even you. :) Simplify. Use some temporary variables.

Comment: You can simplify things by using the `toupper` function from `<ctype.h>`, e.g. `if (toupper(coffee_strength) == 'M' && toupper(coffee1_type) == 'L')`

Comment: The correct way to code this is to create a coffee struct with a specialized comparison/lookup functions.

Answer (score 5):

Operator `&&` has higher precedence than operator `||`. Therefore, though legal, the compiler is telling you code that does this:

```
a && b || c && d
```

May not be doing what you intended. The compiler will treat that as

```
(a && b) || (c && d)
```

but for all it knows, you intended any one of a number of other things.

Perhaps this:

```
a && (b || (c && d))
```

or... this:

```
((a && b) || c) && d
```

Or maybe... this:

```
a && (b || c) && d
```

etc.

It makes a difference, and mistakes like this are common, so although your code will compile, it will do so with warnings when appropriately asked to do so (and it's *always* appropriate to ask). Not because it is *wrong*, but rather because you didn't make intent clear enough that the warning monkeys were subdued (which in this case, and most cases, is a good thing) To ensure you get what you expected, the compiler is asking you to clarify your expression via parenthesis. The -Wlogical-op-parentheses, included with -Wall, is the likely candidate telling you this if you're using gcc or clang.

By the looks of it, you've taken up the mantle of trying to address this, but you missed several instances. For example:

```
((coffee_servings >= 1) && (coffee_servings <= 4) &&
 (coffee1_weight >= 0) && (coffee1_weight <= 250) || // <== here
 ((coffee_servings >= 1) && (coffee_servings <= 9) &&
 (coffee1_weight == 500)) || 
 ((coffee_servings >= 10) && (coffee1_weight == 1000)))
```

There are others below, which I leave for you to find (they're pretty obvious once you start nesting your parens and realize just how many places `a && b || c` pops up).

```
(((coffee_cream == 'y' || coffee_cream == 'Y') &&
  (coffee1_cream == 'y' || coffee1_cream == 'Y') ||
  (coffee_cream == 'n' || coffee_cream == 'N') &&
  (coffee1_cream == 'n' || coffee1_cream == 'N'))),
```

and here:

```
((coffee1_temp >= 60.0) && (coffee1_temp <= 69.9) &&
 (coffee_maker == 'r' || coffee_maker == 'R') || // <== here
 ((coffee1_temp >= 70.0) && (coffee_maker == 'c' || coffee_maker == 'C')))
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to say, but that seems like making out everything by looking at space. There are millions of stars, planets, asteroids, comets, meteors.

But I extremely appreciate your effort on formatting. Not a joke.

The problem seems to be here:

```
                            && (coffee1_temp <= 69.9) &&
     (coffee_maker == 'r' || coffee_maker == 'R') || 
     ((coffee1_temp >= 70.0) && (coffee_maker == 'c' ||  coffee_maker == 'C'))));
```

Let's expand it:

```
&& (coffee1_temp <= 69.9) && (coffee_maker == 'r' || coffee_maker == 'R') || ((coffee1_temp >= 70.0) && (coffee_maker == 'c' ||  coffee_maker == 'C'))));
```

I am not sure what you want to acheive in that line, but here is a example that might fix the error in that line:

```
&& (coffee1_temp <= 69.9) && ( (coffee_maker == 'r' || coffee_maker == 'R') || ((coffee1_temp >= 70.0) && (coffee_maker == 'c' ||  coffee_maker == 'C')) ) ));
```

Why does the error happen?
You have a `a || c && d`/`a && b || c && d`. The compiler warns you since you did not tell it what to do in that situation.

Example:
`a && c || c && d`,
What should happen first? `c || c` or `a && c` or `c || c && d`, etc... Extremely confusing...

### Edit:

It also seems like you have this on many other places too.
You could just use separate if statements to make this clearer...after all it seems like it takes more time to read this than to write a new set of if statements.

Hopefully more readable:

```
(
    (coffee_strength == 'm' || coffee_strength == 'M')
 && (coffee1_type == 'l' || coffee1_type == 'L')
 || (coffee_strength == 'r' || coffee_strength == 'R')
 && (coffee1_type == 'b' || coffee1_type == 'B')
),



(
    (coffee_maker == 'r' || coffee_maker == 'R')
 && (coffee1_grindSize == 'c' || coffee1_grindSize == 'C')
 || (coffee_maker == 'C' || coffee_maker == 'c')
 && (coffee1_grindSize == 'f' || coffee1_grindSize == 'F')
),



(
    (coffee_servings >= 1)
 && (coffee_servings <= 4)
 && (coffee1_weight >= 0)
 && (coffee1_weight <= 250)
 || (
        (coffee_servings >= 1)
     && (coffee_servings <= 9)
     && (coffee1_weight == 500)
    )
 || (
        (coffee_servings >= 10)
     && (coffee1_weight == 1000)
    )
),



(
    (
        (coffee_cream == 'y' || coffee_cream == 'Y')
     && (coffee1_cream == 'y' || coffee1_cream == 'Y')
     || (coffee_cream == 'n' || coffee_cream == 'N')
     && (coffee1_cream == 'n' || coffee1_cream == 'N')
    )
),



(
    (coffee1_temp >= 60.0)
 && (coffee1_temp <= 69.9)
 && (coffee_maker == 'r' || coffee_maker == 'R')
 || (
        (coffee1_temp >= 70.0)
     && (coffee_maker == 'c' ||  coffee_maker == 'C')
    )
)
```

Now, is it really hard to make out what the issues are?

Fix, **THAT MIGHT NOT BEHAVE AS YOU INTENDED**:

```
(
    (
        (coffee_strength == 'm' || coffee_strength == 'M')
     && (coffee1_type == 'l' || coffee1_type == 'L')
    )
 || (
        (coffee_strength == 'r' || coffee_strength == 'R')
     && (coffee1_type == 'b' || coffee1_type == 'B')
    )
)



(
    (
        (coffee_maker == 'r' || coffee_maker == 'R')
     && (coffee1_grindSize == 'c' || coffee1_grindSize == 'C')
    )
 || (
        (coffee_maker == 'C' || coffee_maker == 'c')
     && (coffee1_grindSize == 'f' || coffee1_grindSize == 'F')
    )
)



(
    (
        (coffee_servings >= 1)
     && (coffee_servings <= 4)
     && (coffee1_weight >= 0)
     && (coffee1_weight <= 250)
    )
 || (
        (coffee_servings >= 1)
     && (coffee_servings <= 9)
     && (coffee1_weight == 500)
    )
 || (
        (coffee_servings >= 10)
     && (coffee1_weight == 1000)
    )
)



(
    (
        (
            (coffee_cream == 'y' || coffee_cream == 'Y')
         && (coffee1_cream == 'y' || coffee1_cream == 'Y')
        )
     || (
            (coffee_cream == 'n' || coffee_cream == 'N')
         && (coffee1_cream == 'n' || coffee1_cream == 'N')
        )
    )
)



(
    (
        (coffee1_temp >= 60.0)
     && (coffee1_temp <= 69.9)
     && (coffee_maker == 'r' || coffee_maker == 'R')
    )
 || (
        (coffee1_temp >= 70.0)
     && (coffee_maker == 'c' ||  coffee_maker == 'C')
    )
)
```

And as @user3386109 said, you can simplify statements checking for uppercase and lowercase like `a == 'A' || a == 'a'` to `toupper(a) == 'A'` using `toupper(int c)` and `tolower(int c)` from `<ctype.h>`